# Encoding problem: ucs2_bin collate does not support cyrillic and greek languages

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, internationalization, ucs2

I need to store and compare text in several language in a field of a Mysql database. Actually, I set uc2 for character set and ucs_bin for collate, and I find that it does not work for cyrillic and greek characters.
How can I solve this problem? Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance
Teodoro

Answer (score 0):

Use `utf8` as a character set, with collation `utf8_unicode_ci` -- it is the most robust combination (although slightly slower than using `utf8_general_ci`).

Comment: the `_ci` stands for case-insensitive and compares accented characters the same, too. Use collation `utf8_bin` to distinguish between accented characters and case.